# Updating OS to 10.7.3 with slow internet

Tags: mac-appstore

My internet connection is very slow, and I need to update my OS to 10.7.3. Can someone give me step-by-step instructions as in how to download from another computer and install it on my MacBook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the 10.7.3 combo update from here:

http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1484

Burn it to DVD (or split it and burn to 3 CDs).

Run it on the target machine.  It must already be running 10.7.0 or later for this update to install.

If you want to update other Apple software offline, this page has links to many of the common Apple updates:

http://support.apple.com/downloads

Comment: Thank you and could you also help me find a suitable link to download xCode 4.3.2 please (i need to download this separately from another machine and install it on mine). I need the link for the full installation of xCode 4.3.2

Comment: @illep For the full installation you need to load the app store on the computer with the better internet connection, and select xCode (or get it through the developer website if you have a developer account).  Once it's downloaded you'll have an installation disk image.  Copy that to your target computer and run it to install.

Comment: So if i transfer the dmg file to the other Mac and double click on the dmg file, wont it auto-install ? Is it a must to burn it to a dvd ?

Comment: @illep I don't understand your question.  If you move the dmg of the downloaded installation image to the mac you want to install it on, whether via DVD, USB flash drive, or some other method, it should install just fine.